# Easiest way to add dropdown to a page

Tags: plugins, php, menus, navigation, dropdown

I am trying to add a dropdown menu to my page (**not menu or widget section**) and once the user selects an item from that menu, it redirects to a specific page. I have tried using the block editor, but there is no dropdown menu nor shortcodes so that I can add a menu. My website has multiple versions of documents and I want the user to be able to select the version and go to that page automatically